# Python-Django utf-8 csv.writer

Tags: python, django, csv, utf-8

im using **python csv library** for exporting my models into a csv file in django.
codes are like this :

```
import csv
from django.http import HttpResponse

def some_view(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['First row', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])
    writer.writerow(['Second row', 'A', 'B', 'C', '"Testing"', "Here's a quote"])

    return response
```

**My problem :**
in my database i have some persian characters that just works with utf-8 encoding format , so when i open generated csv file in excel the persian characters not shown correctly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

i try encode('UTF-8') Solution in some cases, but the result in microsoft excel is not readable , it shows b'\xd8\xb1\xdb\x8c\xd8'.
However i find the correct way for showing CSV in excel readable.

```
import csv
from django.http import HttpResponse

def some_view(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'

    response.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['First row', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])
    writer.writerow(['Second row', 'A', 'B', 'C', '"Testing"', "Here's a quote"])

    return response
```

Just add **response.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))** into the code

Comment: i quess u should try encode('utf8') at writer.writerrow not in response.write

Comment: so it doesn't ask user to encoding ? while opening?

Answer (score 5):

just add this new line code :

```
response.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8)
```

after this line :

```
 response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'
```

Comment: This was what worked for me! Simply adding this excel will decode Chinese characters correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use this i have arabic character and worked fine for me

```
def university_csv(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="university_list.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    university_obj = Universities.objects.using('cms').all()
    writer.writerow(['id', 'NAME', 'ABBREVIATION', 'ADDRESS'])
    for item in university_obj:
        if item.address:
            if item.abbreviation:
                writer.writerow([item.id, item.name.encode('UTF-8'), item.abbreviation.encode('UTF-8'),
                                 item.address.encode('UTF-8')])
            else:
                writer.writerow([item.id, item.name.encode('UTF-8'), item.abbreviation, item.address.encode('UTF-8')])
        else:
            if item.abbreviation:
                writer.writerow([item.id, item.name.encode('UTF-8'), item.abbreviation.encode('UTF-8')])
            else:
                writer.writerow([item.id, item.name.encode('UTF-8')])

    return response
```

Comment: u can see the format for utf and ignore the if else condition.

Comment: i try this before but the result is not a readable string its utf-8 literal like \xd8\x80 or some thing like that.

Comment: what you mean ?

Comment: u must have written  utf code somewhere can u please write your updated code

Answer (score -1):

First of all add a:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

At the top of your .py file. Second, it's not an Django issue, it's rather the MS Excel issue. I had a similar problem last week and found that in excel when you choose the encoding you just need to set the language code (or something like that) to UTF-8 family rather the Persian.

Comment: If you open the .csv file in a normal notepad and you see your letters then everything is ok'ey with the file.

Comment: If something is wrong with the letters then add the .encode('UTF-8') on the fields that have your letters.